# How to use ScrollView inside a RecyclerView in android Studio

Tags: android

I want to add ScrollView in TextView.

Like when TextView exceeds one particular height then ScrollView perform its task.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you could add some code showing what you have tried/are trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add ScrollView inside a TextView. Instead you can apply scrolling feature to a TextView. To apply scrolling behaviour do the following.

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hyderabad"
    android:id="@+id/sample"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:maxLines="40"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

In Java code use the following

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sample);
tv.setText("Long long ..................add more text here........text");
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Comment: Thanks, Gnanendra Kumar. I really appericiate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your textView in a LinearLayout or anykind of Layout and then you have to wrap it with your scrollView in your XML like this.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1">

   <LinearLayout
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

   </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

ScrollView only takes Layouts (Linear, Grid...)

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I have problem like and do something like:

fragment_chat.xml

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/messages_scroll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/send_panel"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/messages"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And i declare textView with other files like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/chat_msg_user"
android:padding="5dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/user_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textStyle="italic"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/msg_body"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/user_name"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

and everything works fine :D

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a ScrollView actually.

Just set the

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"

android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

properties of your TextView in your layout's xml file.

Then use:

```
yourTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

in your code.

Bingo, it scrolls!